# Honeywell's Captuvo SL22 SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipod-touch, titanium-modules

I am looking for help in integrating Captuvo SL22 SDK within appcelerator. The Captuvo SDK comes with the Captuvo scanner/msr for ipod. I am trying to use Captuvo SDK in a custom module and call it in the main app. I am able to establish a connection with the Captuvo Device by using the following code in the custom module startup method:

```
-(void) startup{
    self.captuvo = [Captuvo sharedCaptuvoDevice];
    [self.captuvo addCaptuvoDelegate:self];
    [self.captuvo startDecoderHardware];
}

-(void) DecoderReady{
    //Fire Event successfully to Titanium App
}
```

After the startup I try to turn the scanner on by hitting a button in the app, this is my code:

```
-(void) turnScannerOn{
    if([self.captuvo isDecoderRunning]){
        //Fire event successfully to Titanium App
        [self.captuvo startDecoderScanning];
    }
}
```

However, no matter what I try I cannot get the scanner to turn on for the life of me. I am using Titanium 3.1.1 for an iPod touch running iOS 6.1. Any help would be much appreciated! If I figure it out I will be sure to let others know!

Update:
So an update on this is that I was able to get the this to kind of work. This to the tiapp.xml to scan:

```
<ios>
    <plist>
        <dict>
            <key>UISupportedExternalAccessoryProtocols</key>
            <array>
                <string>com.honeywell.scansled.protocol.decoder</string>
                <string>com.honeywell.scansled.protocol.msr</string>
                <string>com.honeywell.scansled.protocol.pm</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </plist>
</ios>
```

However, when you first startup the app, I am unable to turn on the scanner using a button, but the triggers on the side work, but no data is returned. Honeywell provided some sample code and I noticed that this code added to a native app makes the scanner work on the initial start up so I was wondering if there is a way to replicate this objective C code inside of titanium:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[Captuvo sharedCaptuvoDevice] removeCaptuvoDelegate:self] ;
    [[Captuvo sharedCaptuvoDevice] addCaptuvoDelegate:self];
    [[Captuvo sharedCaptuvoDevice] startPMHardware];
    [[Captuvo sharedCaptuvoDevice] startDecoderHardware];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [[Captuvo sharedCaptuvoDevice] stopDecoderHardware];
    [[Captuvo sharedCaptuvoDevice] stopPMHardware];
    [[Captuvo sharedCaptuvoDevice] removeCaptuvoDelegate:self];
}
```

Comment: Same exact problem. Added the external protocals worked for me. <3

Comment: What do you mean by external protocols? Are you referring to the plist? Or are there more that I am missing? Also where should the external protocols be added? They can be added in both the tiapp.xml file or in a plist file in the module itself, where did you put the plist?

Comment: I just added the protocols to the plist with the "Supported external accessory protocols"

Comment: Are there any protocols that I am missing from my code above?

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you have the "Supported external accesories" key set in the info.plist as follows:

```
<string>com.honeywell.scansled.protocol.decoder</string>
<string>com.honeywell.scansled.protocol.msr</string>
<string>com.honeywell.scansled.protocol.pm</string>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the check for isDecoderRunning. If you haven't started the decoder, it will never return true, and you will never reach the code where you are starting the decoder.

Also, make sure you are starting both the barcode and the MSR:

```
    [self.captuvo startDecoderScanning];
    [self.captuvo startMSRHardware];
```

I would also recommend doing this:

```
    connectionStatus = [captuvo startDecoderHardware];
    switch (connectionStatus) {
        case ProtocolConnectionStatusConnected:
        case ProtocolConnectionStatusAlreadyConnected:
            NSLog(@"Connected!");
            break;
        case ProtocolConnectionStatusBatteryDepleted:
            NSLog(@"Battery depleted!");
            break;
        case ProtocolConnectionStatusUnableToConnect:
            NSLog(@"Error connecting!");
            break;
        case ProtocolConnectionStatusUnableToConnectIncompatiableSledFirmware:
            NSLog(@"Incompatible firmware!");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
```

That way you can check what happened when trying to connect.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, but check out my update. The weird thing about what I was able to figure out was that everything seems to connect ok, but no data gets returned from the scan. It makes the beep sound that indicates a successful scan.

Comment: The light doesn't even comes one? I think I run into a similar problem once, and the issue was the old firmware with the newest SDK. Have you tried updating the firmware? If I'm not wrong, the devices are usually shipping with the firmware 1.3, and if you are using the latest SDK they won't work until you update the firmware, which I found here [link](http://www.honeywellaidc.com/Captuvo/Thank-You-SDK-Request2.html). I was not able to update to the latest firmware, so I had to go with 1.6. You will also need a Windows machine to update that.

Comment: You are correct, the devices ship with firmware 1.3 and I was able to update the firmware on the device. Never understood why you have to update the firmware on a Windows computer for a device that is meant to work with Apple devices. The scanner light comes on and it beeps like it read the barcode, but nothing comes back when I open the app initially. I am able to scan successfully after I pause the app by hitting the home button and then resuming the app by going back into the app.

Comment: You mean the delegate method is just called after you click home button and go back into the app? When are you initializing the captive?

Comment: I initialize the device when I open the screen that I need to do the scanning on for the App.

Comment: Just to make sure, are you implementing the decoderDataReceived: method?

Comment: Yes I am implementing decoderDataReceived method to let me know when something was scanned.

Comment: If you could create a sample project where you can replicate the issue and share with me, I could take a look. You seem to be doing everything the right way so far.

Comment: Alright so after about 6 months or so we are coming back around on this issue. I have added debugging to make sure that the device is connected (and it is) to making sure the decoder is ready for use (which it is). The issue seems to be with the Captuvo not returning anything from the scan, but I know the scanner is ready and turned on. I don't do anything fancy with the dataReceived function just trying to put out to the NSLog what data was received from the barcode scanner.

Comment: I don't have access to Captuvo hardware anymore, so there's not much I can help. Another think that you might want to check is make sure that the barcode you are scanning is enabled. The manual has some codes to enable/disable specific barcodes.

Comment: I was successful finally. I just made sure that I declared all of my functions in objective C and it started working. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

@Chris 
For ur update question , i have wrote same code like u , stop stopDecoderHardware in viewWillDiseappear and startDecoderHardware in viewWillAppear , then no data gets occasionaly but the light is always OK,so i guessd there are some problems caused by the start and stop ,then i removed all stopDecoderHardware and startDecoderHardware methods in my viewController , just retain the addDelegate and removeDelegate methods, and modify the method in AppDelegate.m file like below

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [[Captuvo sharedCaptuvoDevice] startDecoderHardware];
}  
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [[Captuvo sharedCaptuvoDevice] stopDecoderHardware];
}
```

yep,wasting batteries maybe,but it seems that solving the problem that no data gets

Comment: I was successful finally. I just made sure that I declared all of my functions in objective C and it started working. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

This post is getting old, but I thought I'd put my 2 cents in to help out if anyone else stumbles upon this question.

I've found that I need to call `startDecoderHardware` on the main UI thread or I won't get barcode scan callbacks. I spent a lot of time fighting this before I figured that out.

Answer (score -1):

When you start use the Honeywell's Captuvo SDK, you need read the quick start and release notes first, that will help you quick start develop you self application base CaptuvoSDK for SL22/SL42/SL62