# CodenameOne - ObjectiveC Bridge - converting C header definition to ObjC Bridge

Tags: codenameone

I have an Objective C method for the Honeywell Captuvo SL22 which the SDK says I can use to receive the scanned in barcode data:

```
-(void)decoderDataReceived:(NSString*)data;
```

which I am trying to use in the ObjectiveC Bridge like so:

```
Objc.DelegateObject delegate = Objc.makeDelegate()
    .add("decoderDataReceived:", Method.create(Method.ArgType.Void , new Method.ArgType[]{Method.ArgType.CString},args ->
    {
        Log.p("Received " + args[0]);
        return null;
    }));
Objc.eval(captuvoShared, "addCaptuvoDelegate:", delegate);
```

However, even though I have successfully connected to the scanner and when I do a scan which shows the scanner light and beeps, the "decoderDataReceived" method isn't called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Objective-C, `NSString` is just a regular object (i.e. it's a subclass of `NSObject`), so you would use `ArgType.Object` for the parameter type.  The `ArgType.CString` parameter type would be used for `const char*`.

So just change your code to

```
Objc.DelegateObject delegate = Objc.makeDelegate()
    .add("decoderDataReceived:", Method.create(Method.ArgType.Void , new Method.ArgType[]{Method.ArgType.Object},args ->
    {
        Log.p("Received " + args[0]);
        return null;
    }));
Objc.eval(captuvoShared, "addCaptuvoDelegate:", delegate);
```

And you should be good.

Comment: I have changed the CString to Object but the method still doesn't seem to be called when I scan. The Honeywell SDK says to check the result of startDecoderHardware method which will return a ProtocolConnectionStatus enumeration but I am not sure how to get this enumeration value? At the moment I just call it like this Objc.eval(captuvoShared,"startDecoderHardware");

Comment: An enum is really just an int.  You can check which int corresponds with with value by looking at the header definition for the enum.  If it doesn't explicitly set a number, then the first value is 0, the second is 1, etc...  https://github.com/DataSplice/HoneywellScanner/blob/master/src/ios/Honeywell/Captuvo.h#L18 .  You also might find this thread helpful.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18084791/honeywells-captuvo-sl22-sdk .

Comment: Yes! I now have a correct response from startDecoderHardware and that link you shared showed (in a roundabout way) that I needed to use createPeerComponent. I can now receive the barcode data. Many, many thanks!